# Appium inspector give error "Original error: App with bundle identifier 'xxxx' unknown

Tags: xcode, appium, appium-ios, appium-inspector

I am quite new to Appium testing and I am trying to use Appium inspector https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector.

I run my app 'IntegrationApp' on iOS simulator in Xcode. The bundle identifier shown in Xcode for 'IntegrationApp' is 'com.facebook.IntegrationApp'

[image]

And 'IntegrationApp' is running successfully on simulator

[image]

Then when I try to connect Appium inspector to app 'IntegrationApp' on simulator, it gives error 'Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: App with bundle identifier 'com.facebook.IntegrationApp' unknown'

[image]

What might the issue be?

Incidentally, the app comes from Appium installation and the 'WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj' project is under .../node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent, so I assume it's a normal app to use for simulator, i.e. no need of signing etc.

I also tried other app that should already exist on simulator, like app store, but it's giving the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you what exactly is the issue but this app is not meant to be used like this. If you just want to get familiar I would advise you to use any of the native iOS apps - like Settings, Camera or whatever. You can find their bundle IDs [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depece748c41/web)

Comment: It does not seem to be the issue. I tried App Store and it gives the same error. see my edited post.

Comment: I tried Settings app. now it works. don't know why different app has different behaviour, but at least it works.

Comment: The list I linked was updated last year, so it is possible that the bundle ID for AppStore is no longer the same on latest iOS(if you use latest). At least you should never encounter this issue while automating your apps